# Cannot boot Arch Linux after installing it next to windows 10

Tags: boot, archlinux

I have just succesfully installed Arch Linux on my Laptop that also runs windows 10. My problem is that there is no visible boot menu where I can choose my os, it always just starts windows. when I run

```
cfdisk
```

it lacks the option of adding a bootable flag to my linux partition.

Is there any way of adding a boot menu?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you follow the Arch Linux installation guide ?

Comment: perhaps http://unix.stackexchange.com is a better fit for this question.

Comment: So, it's never booted into _Arch Linux_?  How have you verified that the installation was successful?

Comment: use os-prober so it will check for another os, then install and config your boot loader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Dual boot with windows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows)

You can install [system-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot)

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt   
mkdir /mnt/boot  
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot  #mount EFI
```

run this command to install bootloader

```
bootctl install
```

And then

```
cp /usr/share/systemd/bootctl/arch.conf /boot/loader/entries/
```

Now just modify the arch.conf and enjoy your archlinux.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i forgot about this post after fixing it with rEFIne bootloader